# Scroll to an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have this `input` element:

```
  <input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="subject" name="subject">
```

Then I have some other elements, like other  tag's & `<textarea>` tag's, etc...

When the user clicks on the `<input id="#subject">`, the page should scroll to the page's last element, and it should do so with a nice animation *(It should be a scroll to bottom and not to top)*.

The last item of the page is a `submit` button with `#submit`:

```
<input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Ok, Done.">
```

The animation should not be too fast and should be fluid.

I am running the latest jQuery version. I prefer to not install any plugin but to use the default jQuery features to achieve this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: `scrollTo` was disabled for me because of a chrome plugin, not sure which.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53873376/2968762 is the best answer (since javascript tag is also used). Not sure why it's blocked unnecessarily.

Answer (score 4540, accepted):

Assuming you have a button with the id `button`, try this example:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

I got the code from the article *[Smoothly scroll to an element without a jQuery plugin](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/posts/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2)*. And I have tested it on the example below.

```html
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#click").click(function (){
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#div1").offset().top
                }, 2000);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="div1" style="height: 1000px; width 100px">
        Test
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="div2" style="height: 1000px; width 100px">
        Test 2
    </div>
    <button id="click">Click me</button>
</html>
```

Comment: This will not work in all cases. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905867/how-to-scroll-to-specific-item-using-jquery

Comment: If you don't want animation, and instead want to jump instantly to the element, use [`.scrollTop(…)`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) instead of `.animate({scrollTop: …}, …)`.

Comment: If you are trying to read that article, here's a working link: [Smoothly scroll to an element without a jQuery plugin](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/posts/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2/)

Comment: For some reason when I use this method, the scroll is locked in at the location. I can't scroll anywhere else.

Comment: if we want to scroll a dialog element to an element inside it, we can change the $('html, body') to our $("#id_of_dialog").

Answer (score 570):

**jQuery .scrollTo():  [View - Demo, API, Source](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)**

I wrote this lightweight plugin to make page/element scrolling much easier. It's flexible where you could pass in a target element or specified value. Perhaps this could be part of jQuery's next official release, what do you think?

---

**Examples Usage:**

```
$('body').scrollTo('#target'); // Scroll screen to target element

$('body').scrollTo(500); // Scroll screen 500 pixels down

$('#scrollable').scrollTo(100); // Scroll individual element 100 pixels down
```

---

**Options:**

*scrollTarget*: A element, string, or number which indicates desired scroll position.

*offsetTop*: A number that defines additional spacing above scroll target.

*duration*: A string or number determining how long the animation will run.

*easing*: A string indicating which easing function to use for the transition.

*complete*: A function to call once the animation is complete.

Comment: $('body') didn't work in FF, so tried $('html, body') which worked.

Comment: If anyone need's this script source, then here you can get it http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js

Comment: I get `scrollTo is not a function`

Answer (score 493):

If you are not much interested in the smooth scroll effect and just interested in scrolling to a particular element, you don't require some jQuery function for this. Javascript has got your case covered:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollIntoView

So all you need to do is: `$("selector").get(0).scrollIntoView();`

`.get(0)` is used because we want to retrieve the JavaScript's DOM element and not the JQuery's DOM element.

## UPDATE

now is possible to scroll with animation, passing scroll options (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#parameters)). You can even control the block position. It seems to have large support, except for [Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#browser_compatibility)

```js
$("selector").get(0).scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
```

Comment: Could you also use `$(selector)[0]`?

Comment: RobW, yes you can just use [0], but get(0) protects you against undefined or negative indexes. See the source:  http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.get

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery at all, just use `document.getElementById('#elementID').scrollIntoView()`. No use loading a ~100k library just to select an element and then convert it to regular JavaScript.

Comment: @Gavin I'm sure you meant that to be: `document.getElementById('elementID').scrollIntoView()`

Comment: Would be nice to be able to define an offset ... https://stackoverflow.com/q/24665602/1066234

Comment: Thank you very much! There are also properties `block` (to define vertical alignment `start`, `center`, `end`, or `nearest`) and `inline` (to define horizontal alignment). Example: `{behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center'}`

Answer (score 106):

This is achievable without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("element-id").scrollIntoView();
```

Answer (score 59):

Using this simple script

```
if($(window.location.hash).length > 0){
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top}, 1000);
}
```

Would make in sort that if a hash tag is found in the url, the scrollTo animate to the ID. If not hash tag found, then ignore the script.

Answer (score 47):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate( {
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-40
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
      window.location.hash = target;
    } );
  } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul role="tablist">
  <li class="active" id="p1"><a href="#pane1" role="tab">Section 1</a></li>
  <li id="p2"><a href="#pane2" role="tab">Section 2</a></li>
  <li id="p3"><a href="#pane3" role="tab">Section 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="pane1"></div>
<div id="pane2"></div>
<div id="pane3"></div>
```

Comment: To make it more universal and to remove unnecessary placing of hashtag into browser link window I just tweaked the code as below:
`jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on( "click", 'a[href^="#"]', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

  $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $target.offset().top - 100}, 1000);
  });
});`

Answer (score 44):

This is the way I do it.

```
document.querySelector('scrollHere').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
```

Works in any browser.

It can easily be wrapped into a function

```
function scrollTo(selector) {
    document.querySelector(selector).scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
}
```

Here is a working example

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  document.getElementById("scrollHere").scrollIntoView( {behavior: "smooth" })
})
```

```css
.btn {margin-bottom: 500px;}
.middle {display: block; margin-bottom: 500px; color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn">Scroll down</button>

<h1 class="middle">You see?</h1>

<div id="scrollHere">Arrived at your destination</div>
```

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: Pretty short and sweet.  One thing to note - I think this only scrolls it into view (could be at the bottom of the viewport) rather than scrolling it to the top of the viewport, as setting scrollTop does.

Comment: I also used this solution, but at least Chrome version 92 for some reason has the smooth scrolling disabled by default, so this solution doesn't work anymore (as of writing this). Quite disappointing actually. It can still be enabled manually by selecting "**Enabled**" (instead of "Default") for the `chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling` configuration.

Answer (score 42):

The solution by Steve and Peter works very well.

But in some cases, you may have to convert the value to an integer. Strangely, the returned value from `$("...").offset().top` is sometimes in `float`.
Use: `parseInt($("....").offset().top)`

For example:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: parseInt($("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top)
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 25):

A compact version of "animate" solution.

```
$.fn.scrollTo = function (speed) {
    if (typeof(speed) === 'undefined')
        speed = 1000;

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: parseInt($(this).offset().top)
    }, speed);
};
```

Basic usage: `$('#your_element').scrollTo();`

Answer (score 21):

With [this solution](https://jsfiddle.net/k148ccg9/) you do not need any plugin and there's ***no setup required*** besides placing the script before your closing `</body>` tag.

```
$("a[href^='#']").on("click", function(e) {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top
  }, 1000);
  return false;
});

if ($(window.location.hash).length > 1) {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
  }, 1000);
}
```

On load, if there is a hash in the address, we scroll to it.

And - whenever you click an `a` link with an `href` hash e.g. `#top`, we scroll to it.

##Edit 2020

If you want a pure JavaScript solution: you could perhaps instead use something like:

```
var _scrollToElement = function (selector) {
  try {
    document.querySelector(selector).scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(e);
  }
}

var _scrollToHashesInHrefs = function () {
  document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='#']").forEach(function (el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      _scrollToElement(el.getAttribute('href'));
      return false;
    })
  })
  if (window.location.hash) {
    _scrollToElement(window.location.hash);
  }
}

_scrollToHashesInHrefs();
```

Answer (score 18):

If you are only handling scrolling to an input element, you can use `focus()`.  For example, if you wanted to scroll to the first visible input:

```
$(':input:visible').first().focus();
```

Or the first visible input in an container with class `.error`:

```
$('.error :input:visible').first().focus();
```

Thanks to [Tricia Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/832777) for pointing this out!

Answer (score 12):

Easy way to achieve the scroll of page to target div id

```
var targetOffset = $('#divID').offset().top;
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to scroll within an overflow container (instead of `$('html, body')` answered above), working also with absolute positioning, this is the way to do :

```
var elem = $('#myElement'),
    container = $('#myScrollableContainer'),
    pos = elem.position().top + container.scrollTop() - container.position().top;

container.animate({
  scrollTop: pos
}
```

Answer (score 10):

After finding the way to get my code work, I think I should make thing a bit clear:
For using:

```
$('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $("#div1").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

you need to be on top of the page since `$("#div1").offset().top` will return different numbers for different positions you scroll to. If you already scrolled out of the top, you need to specify the exact `pageY` value (see `pageY` definition here: https://javascript.info/coordinates).

So now, the problem is to calculate the `pageY` value of one element. Below is an example in case the scroll container is the body:

```
function getPageY(id) {
    let elem = document.getElementById(id);
    let box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
    return box.top + body.scrollTop; // for window scroll: box.top + window.scrollY;
}
```

The above function returns the same number even if you scrolled somewhere. Now, to scroll back to that element:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: getPageY('div1') }, "slow");
```

Answer (score 9):

Animations:

```
// slide to top of the page
$('.up').click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
    return false;
});

// slide page to anchor
$('.menutop b').click(function(){
    //event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 600);
    return false;
});

// Scroll to class, div
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#target-element").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});

// div background animate
$(window).scroll(function () {

    var x = $(this).scrollTop();

    // freezze div background
    $('.banner0').css('background-position', '0px ' + x +'px');

    // from left to right
    $('.banner0').css('background-position', x+'px ' +'0px');

    // from right to left
    $('.banner0').css('background-position', -x+'px ' +'0px');

    // from bottom to top
    $('#skills').css('background-position', '0px ' + -x + 'px');

    // move background from top to bottom
    $('.skills1').css('background-position', '0% ' + parseInt(-x / 1) + 'px' + ', 0% ' + parseInt(-x / 1) + 'px, center top');

    // Show hide mtop menu  
    if ( x > 100 ) {
    $( ".menu" ).addClass( 'menushow' );
    $( ".menu" ).fadeIn("slow");
    $( ".menu" ).animate({opacity: 0.75}, 500);
    } else {
    $( ".menu" ).removeClass( 'menushow' );
    $( ".menu" ).animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
    }

});

// progres bar animation simple
$('.bar1').each(function(i) {
  var width = $(this).data('width');  
  $(this).animate({'width' : width + '%' }, 900, function(){
    // Animation complete
  });  
});
```

Answer (score 8):

In most cases, it would be best to use a plugin. Seriously. I'm going to [tout mine here](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.scrollable). Of course there are others, too. But please check if they really avoid the pitfalls for which you'd want a plugin in the first place - not all of them do.

I have written about the reasons for using a plugin [elsewhere](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.scrollable#why). In a nutshell, the one liner underpinning most answers here

```
$('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: $target.offset().top }, duration );
```

is bad UX.

- The animation doesn't respond to user actions. It carries on even if the user clicks, taps, or tries to scroll.
- If the starting point of the animation is close to the target element, the animation is painfully slow.
- If the target element is placed near the bottom of the page, it can't be scrolled to the top of the window. The scroll animation stops abruptly then, in mid motion.

To handle these issues (and a [bunch of others](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.scrollable#why)), you can use a plugin of mine, [jQuery.scrollable](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.scrollable). The call then becomes

```
$( window ).scrollTo( targetPosition );
```

and that's it. Of course, there are [more options](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.scrollable#animation-options).

With regard to the target position, `$target.offset().top` does the job in most cases. But please be aware that the returned value doesn't take a border on the `html` element into account ([see this demo](http://jsbin.com/vifugo/3)). If you need the target position to be accurate under any circumstances, it is better to use

```
targetPosition = $( window ).scrollTop() + $target[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

That works even if a border on the `html` element is set.

Answer (score 8):

`$('html, body').animate(...)` does not work for me in the iPhone, Android, Chrome, or Safari browsers.

I had to target the root content element of the page.

> $('#content').animate(...)

Here is what I have ended up with:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|Android)/)) {
    $('#content').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
   }, 'slow');
}
else{
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
    }, 'slow');
}
```

All body content wired up with a #content div

```html
<html>
    ....
    <body>
        <div id="content">
        ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use user agent sniffing. http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/

Comment: Add word-break: break-all; to your CSS element that is in trouble. Android/iOS webview jQuery.animate({scrollTop: y}) position Incorrect. https://medium.com/@ellery.leung/android-ios-webview-jquery-animate-scrolltop-y-position-incorrect-solved-4a66be452a05

Answer (score 7):

This is my approach abstracting the ID's and href's, using a generic class selector

```js
$(function() {
  // Generic selector to be used anywhere
  $(".js-scroll-to").click(function(e) {

    // Get the href dynamically
    var destination = $(this).attr('href');

    // Prevent href=“#” link from changing the URL hash (optional)
    e.preventDefault();

    // Animate scroll to destination
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(destination).offset().top
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- example of a fixed nav menu -->
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#section-1" class="nav-item js-scroll-to">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#section-2" class="nav-item js-scroll-to">Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#section-3" class="nav-item js-scroll-to">Item 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7):

Very simple and easy to use custom jQuery plugin. Just add the attribute `scroll=` to your clickable element and set its value to the selector you want to scroll to.

Like so: `<a scroll="#product">Click me</a>`. It can be used on any element.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.animateScroll = function(){
        console.log($('[scroll]'));
        $('[scroll]').click(function(){
            selector = $($(this).attr('scroll'));
            console.log(selector);
            console.log(selector.offset().top);
            $('html body').animate(
                {scrollTop: (selector.offset().top)}, //- $(window).scrollTop()
                1000
            );
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

// RUN
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $().animateScroll();
});

// IN HTML EXAMPLE
// RUN ONCLICK ON OBJECT WITH ATTRIBUTE SCROLL=".SELECTOR"
// <a scroll="#product">Click To Scroll</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 
  Math.min( 
    $(to).offset().top-margintop, //margintop is the margin above the target
    $('body')[0].scrollHeight-$('body').height()) //if the target is at the bottom
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 4):

To show the full element (if it's possible with the current window size):

```js
var element       = $("#some_element");
var elementHeight = element.height();
var windowHeight  = $(window).height();

var offset = Math.min(elementHeight, windowHeight) + element.offset().top;
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: offset }, 500);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var scrollTo = function($parent, $element) {
    var topDiff = $element.position().top - $parent.position().top;

    $parent.animate({
        scrollTop : topDiff
    }, 100);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

This is Atharva's answer from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollIntoView.
Just wanted to add if your document is in an iframe, you can choose an element in the parent frame to scroll into view:

```
 $('#element-in-parent-frame', window.parent.document).get(0).scrollIntoView();
```

Answer (score 4):

**ONELINER**

```
subject.onclick = e=> window.scroll({top: submit.offsetTop, behavior:'smooth'});
```

```js
subject.onclick = e=> window.scroll({top: submit.offsetTop, behavior: 'smooth'});
```

```css
.box,.foot{display: flex;background:#fdf;padding:500px 0} .foot{padding:250px}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="textfield" value="click here" id="subject" name="subject">

<div class="box">
  Some content
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>

<input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Ok, Done.">

<div class="foot">Some footer</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a general purpose function that scrolls to either a jQuery object, a CSS selector, or a numeric value.

Example usage:

```
// scroll to "#target-element":
$.scrollTo("#target-element");

// scroll to 80 pixels above first element with class ".invalid":
$.scrollTo(".invalid", -80);

// scroll a container with id "#my-container" to 300 pixels from its top:
$.scrollTo(300, 0, "slow", "#my-container");
```

The function's code:

```
/**
* Scrolls the container to the target position minus the offset
*
* @param target    - the destination to scroll to, can be a jQuery object
*                    jQuery selector, or numeric position
* @param offset    - the offset in pixels from the target position, e.g.
*                    pass -80 to scroll to 80 pixels above the target
* @param speed     - the scroll speed in milliseconds, or one of the
*                    strings "fast" or "slow". default: 500
* @param container - a jQuery object or selector for the container to
*                    be scrolled. default: "html, body"
*/
jQuery.scrollTo = function (target, offset, speed, container) {

    if (isNaN(target)) {

        if (!(target instanceof jQuery))
            target = $(target);

        target = parseInt(target.offset().top);
    }

    container = container || "html, body";
    if (!(container instanceof jQuery))
        container = $(container);

    speed = speed || 500;
    offset = offset || 0;

    container.animate({
        scrollTop: target + offset
    }, speed);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

> When the user clicks on that input with #subject, the page should
>   scroll to the last element of the page with a nice animation. It
>   should be a scroll to bottom and not to top.
>
> The last item of the page is a submit button with #submit

```
$('#subject').click(function()
{
    $('#submit').focus();
    $('#subject').focus();
});
```

This will first scroll down to `#submit` then restore the cursor back to the input that was clicked, which mimics a scroll down, and works on most browsers. It also doesn't require jQuery as it can be written in pure JavaScript.

Can this fashion of using `focus` function mimic animation in a better way, through chaining `focus` calls. I haven't tested this theory, but it would look something like this:

```
<style>
  #F > *
  {
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<form id="F" >
  <div id="child_1"> .. </div>
  <div id="child_2"> .. </div>
  ..
  <div id="child_K"> .. </div>
</form>

<script>
  $('#child_N').click(function()
  {
    $('#child_N').focus();
    $('#child_N+1').focus();
    ..
    $('#child_K').focus();

    $('#child_N').focus();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I set up a module [scroll-element](https://github.com/StevenIseki/scroll-element) `npm install scroll-element`. It works like this:

```
import { scrollToElement, scrollWindowToElement } from 'scroll-element'

/* scroll the window to your target element, duration and offset optional */
let targetElement = document.getElementById('my-item')
scrollWindowToElement(targetElement)

/* scroll the overflow container element to your target element, duration and offset optional */
let containerElement = document.getElementById('my-container')
let targetElement = document.getElementById('my-item')
scrollToElement(containerElement, targetElement)
```

Written with help from the following SO posts:

- [offset-top-of-an-element-without-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953144/how-do-i-get-the-offset-top-value-of-an-element-without-using-jquery)
- [scrolltop-animation-without-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474678/scrolltop-animation-without-jquery)

Here is the code:

```
export const scrollToElement = function(containerElement, targetElement, duration, offset) {
  if (duration == null) { duration = 1000 }
  if (offset == null) { offset = 0 }

  let targetOffsetTop = getElementOffset(targetElement).top
  let containerOffsetTop = getElementOffset(containerElement).top
  let scrollTarget = targetOffsetTop + ( containerElement.scrollTop - containerOffsetTop)
  scrollTarget += offset
  scroll(containerElement, scrollTarget, duration)
}

export const scrollWindowToElement = function(targetElement, duration, offset) {
  if (duration == null) { duration = 1000 }
  if (offset == null) { offset = 0 }

  let scrollTarget = getElementOffset(targetElement).top
  scrollTarget += offset
  scrollWindow(scrollTarget, duration)
}

function scroll(containerElement, scrollTarget, duration) {
  let scrollStep = scrollTarget / (duration / 15)
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    if ( containerElement.scrollTop < scrollTarget ) {
      containerElement.scrollTop += scrollStep
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  },15)
}

function scrollWindow(scrollTarget, duration) {
  let scrollStep = scrollTarget / (duration / 15)
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    if ( window.scrollY < scrollTarget ) {
      window.scrollBy( 0, scrollStep )
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  },15)
}

function getElementOffset(element) {
  let de = document.documentElement
  let box = element.getBoundingClientRect()
  let top = box.top + window.pageYOffset - de.clientTop
  let left = box.left + window.pageXOffset - de.clientLeft
  return { top: top, left: left }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer as of 2019:

```
$('body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#subject').offset().top - $('body').offset().top + $('body').scrollTop()
}, 'fast');
```

Comment: You should this selector for body: [document.documentElement, document.body]

AND No need body offset in the equation. $('#subject').offset().top is enough.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, this is how I managed to achieve such behavior for a general element which can be inside a DIV with scrolling. In our case we don't scroll the full body, but just particular elements with overflow: auto; within a larger layout.

It creates a fake input of the height of the target element, and then puts a focus to it, and the browser will take care about the rest no matter how deep within the scrollable hierarchy you are. Works like a charm.

```
var $scrollTo = $('#someId'),
inputElem = $('<input type="text"></input>');

$scrollTo.prepend(inputElem);
inputElem.css({
  position: 'absolute',
  width: '1px',
  height: $scrollTo.height()
});
inputElem.focus();
inputElem.remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
var targetOffset = $('#elementToScrollTo').offset().top;
$('#DivParent').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 2500);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate( {
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-40
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
      window.location.hash = target;
    } );
  } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul role="tablist">
  <li class="active" id="p1"><a href="#pane1" role="tab">Section 1</a></li>
  <li id="p2"><a href="#pane2" role="tab">Section 2</a></li>
  <li id="p3"><a href="#pane3" role="tab">Section 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="pane1"></div>
<div id="pane2"></div>
<div id="pane3"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need:

```
$("selector").get(0).scrollTo(0, 0)
```

Comment: And you can use it with options to smooth the scroll with something like

element.scrollTo({
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it.

Comment: It's easy. "Inside" every jQuery object we have simple javascrip element. You can access it via .get method (https://api.jquery.com/get/#get-index) or simply by calling [0]: $("selector").get(0) of $("selector")[0]. You'll get JS element, like if you got it via document.getElementById("selector_id"). So you can call any JS function, like scrollTo or scrollIntoView.

Answer (score 0):

Will do the trick, but will change your hash. If you use Jquery tabs and want page scrolls to tabs header you can:

```
$('#needed_tab').tab('show');
window.location.hash = '#tabs_block';
```