# jQuery Dialog scroll to element in dialog

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog, scroll

I have the following issue:

I open a dialog box with jQuery UI. This dialog box contains a lot of content, which can't be displayed at once.

Is it possible to scroll to a specific element within the dialog box?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905867/how-to-scroll-to-specific-item-using-jquery)

Answer from previous question:

```
var container = $('div'),
scrollTo = $('#row_8');

container.scrollTop(
    scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
);

// Or you can animate the scrolling:
container.animate({
    scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
});​
```

Comment: Ok I didn't know that this would also work within other contains. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No worries. The dialog box is just another `div` so it will work in that too.

Comment: Yes I testet it and it does. Thanks again.