# Onclick scroll to div id and animate the div

Tags: jquery, css

I have searched and searched on here, the other day there was a great question on Stack I found, and Im not sure if you can save favorite questions .. so now I am trying my darndest to find the damn thing.

The user wanted a click function, like scrollto whereby on click the page scrolls to a specific id, and the div highlights and animates ( in color ) and then fades.

There was a js fiddle for it too, but buggered if I can find it thru my history...

Can anyone point me to what I am looking for.

So you have links like.
[link1] [link2] etc

Example: on click link1 the page scrolls ( using scrollto plugin ) and the div it lands at, glows red then fades bak to normal color.

Its like Chris Coyiers scroll to:
http://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/

But when you get to the div the div glows red background and then fades to white

Comment: Sounds a bit like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905867/how-to-scroll-to-specific-item-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, a combo of jQuery UI's Highlight Effect and the ScrollTo Plugin. You can tweak the options to your liking per their respective docs.
http://jsfiddle.net/pVY2m/

Comment: Goodonya,i apologise at my vagueness with the question, but this is it ! Sweet many thanks. I just wish stack could allow us to save favourited questions etc. Voted

Comment: how do you set the color of the highlighted div ?

Comment: $("#three").effect("highlight", {color:"#b1b1b1"}, 3000);

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you need using jQuery:

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: yer im aware of fieslers plugin, which is what i was referring to. But an example on here, scrolled to a div element and animated the div when it got there ...

Comment: kind of like this http://jsfiddle.net/weissraum/Yy678/ but all divs are white bg and when it reached the div it glowed red and then faded back to white. but without easing.. etc

Comment: Found what I am pretty much looking for: http://djpate.com/portfolio/jSlideto/example/index.html