# Autocomplete scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Vtn5Y/559/

```
var li = $('li');
var liSelected;
$(window).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 40){
        if(liSelected){
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            next = liSelected.next();
            if(next.length > 0){
                liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
            }else{
                liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
            }
        }else{
            liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
        }
    }else if(e.which === 38){
        if(liSelected){
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            next = liSelected.prev();
            if(next.length > 0){
                liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
            }else{
                liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
            }
        }else{
            liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
        }
    }
});
```

Now I wonder how I can make the div scroll down to be able to see the selected item.

Thank you!

Comment: Ps: I want to make it on my own and won't use an autocomplete plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, my first answer had a problem.

try this:

```
var li = $('li');
var liSelected;
$(window).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 40){
        if(liSelected){
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            next = liSelected.next();
            if(next.length > 0){
                liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
            }else{
                liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
            }
        }else{
            liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
        }
    }else if(e.which === 38){
        if(liSelected){
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            next = liSelected.prev();
            if(next.length > 0){
                liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
            }else{
                liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
            }
        }else{
            liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
        }
    }
    $('div').scrollTop(liSelected.position().top - $('div').position().top + $('div').scrollTop());
});
```

[JSFidle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vtn5Y/563/)

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar question here: [How to scroll to specific item using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905867/how-to-scroll-to-specific-item-using-jquery)

Solution is to use the scrollTop property like so:

```
var container = $('div'),
scrollTo = $('#row_8');

container.scrollTop(
    scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
);

// Or you can animate the scrolling:
container.animate({
    scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
});​
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xY7tx/406/

Comment: Thanks! this works when implemented like the answer of FabioG.