# Jquery show_hide, what to add in order to make the page scroll to the bottom of the hidden field once button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button on my website that when clicked, reveals a map. This button can be seen when the page first loads up, but when clicked, the section holding the map slides open and goes out of the screen since the page loads at the top (normal). I essentially want the page to scroll down to the bottom of a div that I select when the button is pushed, but only if the map is out of the screen. If the page is scrolled down, and someone clicks the show map button, I don't want the page to jump up to the bottom of the map.

I tried to figure it out myself, but no luck. Any seasoned jquery coders able to give me some guidance?

Many thanks!

```
    map = mapDiv.gmap3("get");
    infobox = new InfoBox({
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-220, -310),
        closeBoxURL: '',
        enableEventPropagation: true
    });
    mapDiv.delegate('.infoBox .close','click',function () {
        infobox.close();
    });

    jQuery(".slidingDiv").hide();

    jQuery(".show_hide").show();

    jQuery('.show_hide').click(function(){

        lastCenter=map.getCenter();

        jQuery(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();

        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

        map.setCenter(lastCenter);

        return false;

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a animated way to scrollTo a certain element.

```
 $("#buttonID").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#divID").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
```

You could also use the window.scrollTo method

```
   $(document).ready(function()){
   function scroll(){
      if(clicked){
         window.scrollTo(0,750); // scroll to where?
         }         
    )};
```

ScrollTo Plugin

```
$(function() {
    $('yourElementName').click(function() {
        $.scrollTo( '#ElementID', 800); // where 800 is the speed.          
    });
});
```

Or you could use javascript as told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905867/how-to-scroll-to-specific-item-using-jquery).

Hope some solution works out for you.

Comment: I tried to implement some of those examples but it's not quite working out. Not sure if it's conflicting? Sorry, I'm quite new with jquery/javascript. Any way you could show me how to integrate it with my code above? Many, many thanks!