# Scrolling to a element inside a scrollable DIV with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a div that has `overflow: scroll` and I have some elements inside the DIV that are hidden. On click of a button on the page, I want to make the DIV scroll to a particular element inside the DIV.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please include a code snippet. It helps in getting your queries resolved faster.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to scroll to an element inside a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635706/how-to-scroll-to-an-element-inside-a-div)

Comment: Here's a fiddle for your issue http://jsfiddle.net/gyz0Lyh2/1/

Comment: ###This Solved my problem:###
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905867/how-to-scroll-to-specific-item-using-jquery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905867/how-to-scroll-to-specific-item-using-jquery

*Simply Clever! *

Answer (score 75):

You need to read the `offsetTop` property of the div you need to scroll to and then set that offset to the `scrollTop` property of the container `div`. Bind this function the event you want to :

```js
function scrollToElementD(){
    var topPos = document.getElementById('inner-element').offsetTop;
    document.getElementById('container').scrollTop = topPos-10;
}
```

```css
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
}

p {
    height: 80px;
    background: blue;
}
#inner-element {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"><p>A</p><p>B</p><p>C</p><p id="inner-element">D</p><p>E</p><p>F</p></div>
<button onclick="scrollToElementD()">SCROLL TO D</button>
```

```
function scrollToElementD(){
  var topPos = document.getElementById('inner-element').offsetTop;
  document.getElementById('container').scrollTop = topPos-10;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/p3kar5bb/322/  (courtesy @rofrischmann)

Comment: @JoãoPaiva Looks as if `scrollTo()` was added as an inbuilt function. Just rename `scrollTo()` to something else. I'll update the answer and the fiddle.

Comment: Why `topPos - 10`? Why 10 specifically?

Comment: @Sumit Just a random value to leave a little gap from top of the screen.

Answer (score 10):

Just improved it by setting a smooth auto scrolling inside a list contained in a div

https://codepen.io/rebosante/pen/eENYBv

```
var topPos = elem.offsetTop

document.getElementById('mybutton').onclick = function () {
   console.log('click')
  scrollTo(document.getElementById('container'), topPos-10, 600);   
}

function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
    var start = element.scrollTop,
        change = to - start,
        currentTime = 0,
        increment = 20;

    var animateScroll = function(){        
        currentTime += increment;
        var val = Math.easeInOutQuad(currentTime, start, change, duration);
        element.scrollTop = val;
        if(currentTime < duration) {
            setTimeout(animateScroll, increment);
        }
    };
    animateScroll();
}

//t = current time
//b = start value
//c = change in value
//d = duration
Math.easeInOutQuad = function (t, b, c, d) {
    t /= d/2;
    if (t < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
    t--;
    return -c/2 * (t*(t-2) - 1) + b;
};
```

I guess it may help someone :)

Answer (score 9):

Here's a simple pure JavaScript solution that works for a target Number (value for `scrollTop`), target DOM element, or some special String cases:

```
/**
 * target - target to scroll to (DOM element, scrollTop Number, 'top', or 'bottom'
 * containerEl - DOM element for the container with scrollbars
 */
var scrollToTarget = function(target, containerEl) {
    // Moved up here for readability:
    var isElement = target && target.nodeType === 1,
        isNumber = Object.prototype.toString.call(target) === '[object Number]';

    if (isElement) {
        containerEl.scrollTop = target.offsetTop;
    } else if (isNumber) {
        containerEl.scrollTop = target;
    } else if (target === 'bottom') {
        containerEl.scrollTop = containerEl.scrollHeight - containerEl.offsetHeight;
    } else if (target === 'top') {
        containerEl.scrollTop = 0;
    }
};
```

And here are some examples of usage:

```
// Scroll to the top
var scrollableDiv = document.getElementById('scrollable_div');
scrollToTarget('top', scrollableDiv);
```

or

```
// Scroll to 200px from the top
var scrollableDiv = document.getElementById('scrollable_div');
scrollToTarget(200, scrollableDiv);
```

or

```
// Scroll to targetElement
var scrollableDiv = document.getElementById('scrollable_div');
var targetElement= document.getElementById('target_element');
scrollToTarget(targetElement, scrollableDiv);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a ref to the div you wish to scroll to `inner-div` and a ref to the scrollable div `scrollable-div`:

```js
const scrollToDiv = () => {
  const innerDivPos = document.getElementById('inner-div').offsetTop

  document
    .getElementById('scrollable-div')
    .scrollTo({ top: innerDivPos, behavior: 'smooth' })
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollable-div" style="height:100px; overflow-y:auto;">
  <button type="button" style="margin-bottom:500px" onclick="scrollToDiv()">Scroll To Div</button>
  <div id="inner-div">Inner Div</div>
</div>
```