# track a scroll position inside an HTML div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-visualization

I am using `google visualization table` to create an `html` table, and it enables `The header row remains fixed as the user scrolls.`

I got something working like this: http://jsfiddle.net/RjHMH/114/

The problem I am facing is that, when I click a `row` to expand the table, it actually redraw the table, so that the `scroll bar` will always be at the top of the table. Is there anyway I can track the current position of the scroll bar when I click, and set the value back when the table is redrawn?

If it is a `scroll bar` of the `DOM`, I can use:

```
var pos = $('body').scrollTop();
table.draw(view, options);
window.scrollTo(0, pos);
```

Then how to track the scroll bar inside a `div`?

Comment: Have you tried changing `$(body)` to `$('#myDivId')`?

Comment: I do tried, the pos is always `0`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrolling to a element inside a scrollable DIV with pure Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980084/scrolling-to-a-element-inside-a-scrollable-div-with-pure-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("google-visualization-table")[0].children[0].onscroll = function(){
    console.log(this.scrollTop); //check the number in console
}
```

The key is to get the div in js, or use jquery, then you can visit the scrollTop of that div.

Answer (score 3):

```
var currentY = 0;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    currentY = $('selector').offset().top;
    console.log(currentY);
});
```

To get the position on click:

```
$(document).click(function () {
    currentY = $('selector').offset().top;
    console.log(currentY);

});
```

Comment: man, please look carefully about the question, the scroll bar is inside a `div`,  it is not a `body` scroll bar

Comment: Ah, edited. You're looking for `offset()` which contains properties `top` and `left`

Comment: I do not think I understand your answer. Can you show sth in the http://jsfiddle.net/RjHMH/114/?

Comment: I didnt solve your whole problem, I just showed you how to get the current position. Just store that position in a variable that's available to whatever method sets it back to the saved position.