# scroll to a certain ID in my page jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a certain page which holds a iframe and gets **submitted** and then a new message is shown within the iframe, this is a lot shorter then the iframe before so it doesn't go to the point I want it on the page.

Now I want to scroll to the new id using jQuery meaning the user can read it from the top and not have to scroll.

My id of my iframe is "`#iframe-container`".

```
if (window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] == "Test.aspx")
    {
        // jquery here.
    }
```

thanks

Comment: Why not use Html anchors?

Comment: because i want it to happens on the click of the submit not a anchor tag

Comment: Try looking at the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905867/how-to-scroll-to-specific-item-using-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [Smooth scroll to div id jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012495/smooth-scroll-to-div-id-jquery)

Comment: @user4058171 Have you tried researching before asking? This seems like a question that can be answered by a 5 minute google search.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#iframe-container').offset().top }, 1000);
```

You can change 1000 to be less to scroll faster or even to 0 to jump to the ID directly.

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#iframe-container').offset().top }, 0);
```

Answer (score -2):

Cross-window post message API support to communicate to new domain . using post message method.

```
 In iframe page

     iframe.contentWindow.postMessage("your message",iframe.src);

    source page:



    if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
                 if(e.data =="yourmess age"){
                          $(window.parent.document).scrollTop();
                        }
```

Comment: Did you post this answer to the wrong question? It doesn't seem to be related at all.