# scroll page to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i Need to scroll to div but i don't need the div to be on top of page after scrolling

i need it to be in of page how do i do that to be in
**center** of the page.

i see many question that make the scrolling right but to top of page i need it to scroll but make the div in **center** of the page.

i've tried this but this scroll it to top of the page

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#"+div).offset().top},
'slow');
```

thanks

[How to scroll to specific item using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905867/how-to-scroll-to-specific-item-using-jquery)  is scroll to div but make it at top of page not at center

Comment: I don't think its a duplicate.  He knows how to scroll to an item, he wants to modify the exact scroll amount so that the item is centered in the window ("scroll into view") rather than at the top of the window ("scroll to top")

Comment: exactly i need it to scroll the div to center of the page not to top

Comment: Then you need to add half the height of the window and subtract half the height of the div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for the div to be *centered* in the window after scrolling you would need to:

1. Query the browser's window height (this is doable)
2. Query the div's height (this is doable, though you need to be careful: height is not always accurately calculated)
3. Subtract Line 2 from Line 1, then divide by 2
4. Add the result from Line 3 to your `top` value

Note: When your div is *taller* than the browser window, it will still be centered, but the top of the div will be off the screen!

Comment: i thinks it's logicaly right :) thanks for your time my friend

Comment: Actually logically its perfect. Just saw we posted same answer. +1. Great minds think alike. =]

Comment: I was just too burnt out from my own 5-hour wrestle with jQuery UI to want to write any of the *code* to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example centering `div2`: https://jsfiddle.net/2mb44kfa/

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
</div>
<div id="div2">
</div>
<div id="div3">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#div1,
#div3 {
    height: 1000px;
}

#div2 {
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

JS:

```
var winHeight = $(window).height();
var divHeight = $("#div2").height();
var height = (divHeight - winHeight) / 2
$('html, body').animate(
    {
        scrollTop: ($("#div2").offset().top + height) + 'px'
    }, 'slow'
);
```